# Suggest some Multi Level Approval Workflow Plugins for Google Forms with PDF Report

Tags: google-forms

I have installed one plugin name ***Form Publisher*** for Google Form. I have added two email id under ***sharing list*** option of ***sharing options and notification tab*** but I see that where approval has been sent to only one email id not second one.

Can you please help me how can I configure multilevel approval workflow process in Form Publisher. ***If not possible then suggest any other plugin where multilevel approval workflow process can be done for Google Forms***  and also automated PDF will be generated sent to the every person from creation to till last level approval.

Thank You.